# How can i insert UIImages in my circle segments with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uiimage

I made a circle/wheel in SwiftUI with 7 segments and i now i would like to insert images (they are in an Array) in each segment (in center of segment), how can i do it?

[image]

Code :

```
struct WheelShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        let pieSections = 7
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        let smaller = rect.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2.0, dy: lineWidth / 2.0)
        let radius = smaller.width / 2.0

        let segmentAngle = 2.0 / CGFloat(pieSections) * CGFloat(Double.pi)
        
        let imageArray: [UIImage] = [
            UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")!,
            UIImage(systemName: "paintpalette.fill")!,
            UIImage(systemName: "airplane")!,
            UIImage(systemName: "cloud.fill")!,
            UIImage(systemName: "dollarsign.circle.fill")!,
            UIImage(systemName: "book.fill")!,
            UIImage(systemName: "bicycle")!
        ]
        
        // Draw segment dividers
        for index in 1...pieSections {
            let drawAngle = segmentAngle * CGFloat(index) + (360 / 7 / 2 * π / 180)
            let x = radius * cos(drawAngle) + rect.width / 2.0
            let y = radius * sin(drawAngle) + rect.height / 2.0
            let cgpoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
            path.move(to: cgpoint)
            let cgPointLine = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            path.addLine(to: cgPointLine)
        }
        
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: To make that you need to make each segment as separate shape, then it will be possible with overlay & clipping.

Comment: For information, i call the WheelShape like this :
                WheelShape()
            .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.259467423, green: 0.5342320204, blue: 0.7349982858, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 3.0)
            .frame(width: 240, height: 240)
            .overlay(Circle()
                        .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.259467423, green: 0.5342320204, blue: 0.7349982858, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 6.0)
            )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach placing the circle in the background and SF Symbols in the overlay.

WWDC 2019 had a presentation that showed off a ring of wedges with animations. Here is the source:
[Building Custom Views in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/drawing_and_animation/building_custom_views_in_swiftui)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let symbols = ["house.fill", "paintpalette.fill", "airplane", "cloud.fill", "dollarsign.circle.fill", "book.fill", "bicycle"]
    
    var body: some View {
        WheelShape(symbols)
            .stroke(
                Color(.blue), lineWidth: 3.0)
            .background(
                Circle().stroke(Color(.blue), lineWidth: 6.0))
            .overlay(
                annotations.foregroundColor(.purple))
    }
    
    var annotations : some View {
        ZStack {
            let theta = CGFloat(2) * .pi / CGFloat(symbols.count)
            GeometryReader { geo in
                let center = CGPoint(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height / 2)
                let radius = min(geo.size.width / 2, geo.size.height / 2) / 1.5
                ForEach(0..<symbols.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    let offset = theta * CGFloat(index) + theta / 2
                    // place SF Symbol, offset to center, then the radius
                    Image(systemName: symbols[index])
                        .offset(x: center.x, y: center.y)
                        .offset(x: radius * cos(offset), y: radius * sin(offset))
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .offset(x: -10, y: -10) // fudge factor to center symbol in wedge
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct WheelShape: Shape {
        let symbols : [String]
        
        init(_ symbols: [String]) {
            self.symbols = symbols
        }
        
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            // center of the shape we are drawing in
            let center = CGPoint(x: rect.size.width / 2, y: rect.size.height / 2)
            let radius = min(rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2)
            // each angle offset in radians
            let theta = CGFloat(2) * .pi / CGFloat(symbols.count)
            var path = Path()
            
            // enumerate the array so index is available
            symbols.enumerated().forEach({ (index, symbol) in
                let offset = theta * CGFloat(index)
                path.move(to: center)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: radius * cos(offset) + center.x, y: radius * sin(offset) + center.y))
            })
            
            return path
        }
    }
}
```

[Symbols centered in wedge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtfNI.png)

Comment: Wow! Perfect! Thank you so much! Why do we need : init(_ symbols: [String]) {
        self.symbols = symbols
    } ??? I commented it and it works without it...

Comment: You are so welcome. Glad I could help! Swift uses "Memberwise Initialization" as default constructors. The code that was commented was auto-created by the compiler. Paul Hudson covers it here [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/understanding-swift/how-do-swifts-memberwise-initializers-work)

Comment: why you are using 3 offset on Image? you could do the same thing with 1 offset.

Comment: For clarity's sake. Since each component is an input to a plot I split them out. The compiler will mash them into one modifier.